# Android + Couchbase usecase?

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase, couchbase-lite

I am currently developing an application that provides some temporary static, but often changing data.
You can think of it like a telephone book. Most of the entries might never change, but there might be cases where people change their telephone number or move in/out. The dataset isnt  large but has to be available at any time.

My first thought was to implement a clientside-SQLDatabase which queries a backend in certain intervals asking for updates (stored in another database on the backend server). If there was an update since the last query, the updated data will be send over and stored in the local sqldatabase.

Now I stumbled over this interesting looking database model Couchbase. Altough I dont see through it completly by now, if I got it, I can use it to keep the client-side database in sync with the servers database. Is this a usecase for couchbase or should I go with another strategy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

That's a perfect use case for Couchbase. You'll want to check out Couchbase Lite (https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android) and the Sync Gateway (http://docs.couchbase.com/sync-gateway/).